# subject + hatte but no verb in partizip 2

Tags: tense, past-participle

Reading (or trying to) the book Emil und die Detektive, by Erich kästner, I found the following:

> » Wahrscheinlich ist er sehr groß geworden, was? «, fragte Pony Hütchen und schob ihr ganz neues Fahrrad hin und her. Sie hatte es eigentlich gar nicht mitnehmen sollen.

So, in the last sentence I was expecting to see the [Plusquamperfekt](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/perfect/PastPerfect.html) tense, but in this case, the sentence should be something like

*Sie hatte es eigentlich gar nicht **mitgenommen** sollen.*

or

*Sie hatte es eigentlich gar nicht mitnehmen **gesollt**.*

I mean, there must be a verb in the Partizip 2.

Additionally, when I paste "*Sie hatte es eigentlich gar nicht mitnehmen sollen*" on Google Translate, I get "*She should not have taken it with her*", which seems to be a reasonable translation, but it indeed has a "partizip 2"-like verb, that is, taken.

Then, why is there no Partizip 2 verb in that sentence on the book?

Comment: @DavidVogt Oh, okay, the question you linked is about "das Perfekt", but I guess the same thing is happening in the sentence I quoted although it is in the Plusquamperfekt. Is it the case? Thank you!

Comment: @HilderVítorLimaPereira The form of *haben* (*hat*, *hatte*, *hätte* or even infinitive *haben*) does not matter.

Comment: @DavidVogt I got it. The [Wikipedia's page Ersatzinfinitiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv) also says so. Thank you. And I am sorry for the duplicated question. So, I guess that now I must keep it here anyway instead of deleting it, right?

Comment: @HilderVítorLimaPereira You don't have to delete the post. It can still be useful if someone else finds the linked post via this one (e.g. if they search for *Plusquamperfekt sollen* or something like that).

Comment: I think there should be an option for you to accept closing your question *if the linked post answers it*.